# Swipelistview not working

Tags: android, listview, swipe, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

I am trying to use [Swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) in my project but it throws NullPointer saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListViewTouchListener.setFrontView(SwipeListViewTouchListener.java:138)
at com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListViewTouchListener.onTouch(SwipeListViewTouchListener.java:731)
at com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView.onInterceptTouchEvent(SwipeListView.java:630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1852)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
```

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)

I have implemented the library in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
        swipe:swipeActionRight="dismiss"
        swipe:swipeAnimationTime="1000"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="false"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeMode="both"
        swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="20dp"
        swipe:swipeOffsetRight="20dp"
        swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code:

```
private SwipeListView listview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        States states_name[] = new States[] {
                new States("Item 1", "Item A"),
                new States("Item 2", "Item B"),
                new States("Item 3", "Item C"),
                new States("Item 4", "Item D"),
                new States("Item 5", "Item E"),
                new States("Item 6", "Item F"), 
                new States("Item 7", "Item G"),
                new States("Item 8", "Item H")
        };

        StateAdapter adapter = new StateAdapter(this, R.layout.listtoinflate, states_name);

        listview1 = (SwipeListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     listview1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: @androidbug: Try [SwipeToDismiss](https://github.com/torryharris/TH-SwipeToDismiss). It is simple and will get your work done.

Comment: I found the solution. @id/front and @id/back were missing from my layout. I added and it worked :)

Comment: Can you tell me what @+id/front and @+id/back are? are they references to layouts within this same xml file? I'm having trouble setting up this listview in xml

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this...

```
States states_name[] = new States[]
```

be this?...

```
States[] states_name = new States[]
```

Comment: but thats not where the problem is. If I remove this [Swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview), the list works fine. I am unable to get rid of the above said nullpointer exception.

Comment: @GDroid Could you have a quick look here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing elements with id "front" and "back" as specified in your implementations of com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView in your layout. They should be in the listview row layout which in your case should be "R.layout.listtoinflate", which you have in your adapter.

There's some example code here:
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview-sample/blob/master/res/layout/package_row.xml

This problem is also answered in this thread:
[SwipeListView usage NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760155/swipelistview-usage-nullpointerexception)